# Free commutative monoid monad

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads, symmetric-monoidal-categories

Has the monad induced by the free commutative monoid functor already been studied anywhere? Does it have any particular properties (other than not being cartesian)?

I would prefer a reference on category theory rather than functional programming, but anything is good.

Comment: What do you want to know about it?

Comment: I'm just looking for a reference that talks about it. Its name is unfortunately too similar to "free monoid monad" to get enough meaningful search results.

Comment: Yes. It's extremely well studied. It has come up in lots of papers of mine, in recent work of Richard Garner from a very high level perspective, and of course in classical sources such as Mac Lane's book, old work of Kelley, and in the topological literature, where it's called $SP^\infty$, sometimes referred to as the Dold-Thom map. See e.g. Farjoun's book on cellular spaces. If you ask a more precise question, we can help more.

Comment: It may be useful to note that the free monoid is lists or sequences, the free commutative monoid is bags or multisets, and the free commutative and idempotent monoid is sets. Richard Bird has more to say on this ``Boom Hierarchy''.